# How to get innerHTML of each matched element

Tags: jquery, each

I have a lot of `<tr>` elements. Each important one is marked with a class name containing "highlight-delete". How can I iterate over the whole set of them, and write each of their `.innerHTML` to the console? I tried this but it failed

```
            $.each('tr[class*=highlight-delete]', function (index, item) {
              console.log(item.innerHTML);
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter of the `each` function should be an `array` or `object`, you are passing a string:

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

```
  $.each($('tr[class*=highlight-delete]'), function (index, item) {
          console.log(item.innerHTML);
  });
```

Comment: I was just starting to figure that out something was wrong with the input :), kept getting strange results. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @TravisJ You are welcome, you can also use `$('tr[class*=highlight-delete]').each...` which is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery's `html()` `function`

```
 $('tr[class*=highlight-delete]').each(function (index, item) {
      console.log($(item).html());
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware this is an old thread. Wanted to give an alternative to using jquery's `each`.

```
$('tr[class*=highlight-delete]').get().map((currentValue, index, arr) => {return currentValue.innerHTML;})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

this instead

```
item[0].innerHTML;
```

Actually item.innerHTML or $(item).html() will work fine.

item[0] will not as we're not getting a wrapped set but a dom node.

http://jsfiddle.net/adouga/9yqqp/

Answer (score 1):

[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes a collection as its first argument, not a selector, so each *item* is actually each character of your string.

You need to either change the string into a collection by wrapping it in `$()` or using the alternate `$(...).each(function(index, item) {...});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr[class*=highlight-delete]').each(function (index, item) {
  console.log(item.innerHTML);
});​
```

[An example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/hEYLu/)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to approach this would be to simply take advantage of chaining in jQuery. Use `each` on the jQuery object returned. `this` will be bound to the matched element in the callback function.

```
$('tr[class*=highlight-delete]').each(function(){
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```